# Is it safe to use Flexbox and Grid freely by now (2020)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm afraid it's not a code talk but, Flexbox and Grid in CSS3 have always made my life easier. But I can't stop worrying about the browser compatibility. Is it seriously safe to use Flexbox and Grid without hesitation in 2020 (now)?

Comment: It is part of the css3 spec and big  actors follow and implement the css3 spec. what makes you so worried ?

Comment: It is definitely safe to use. Just have a look at caniuse.com and type in flexbox and grid. You see compatibility rises and is already large.

Comment: IE is still widely used by people in my country, unfortunately :(

Comment: It depends entirely on what browsers you have to support.

Comment: Flexbox yes. Grid no, but I use grid with flexbox fallback.

Comment: The "This question already has an answer" question really doesn't answer this question in full, it's only about Grid, while this mentions Flexbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether it's "safe" depends on the percentage of browsers your target audience is using. So the problem can be considered subjective.

There is no fatal instability because at the moment it is rich in polyfills and most modern browsers support flexbox and grid layout.

Support tables of flexbox and grid layout:

- https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Polyfills:

- https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill
- https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility

Comment: what is a pollyfill ?

Comment: @HosMercury A pollyfill in web development most often refers to javascript code that reproduces certain CSS or HTML5 functionality that is not supported by older browsers or devices.

Answer (score 2):

I think so, you can see for yourself here: https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

If you have any doubts you can check in your access log to verify your user's browsers via the user-agent